# How can i copy a txt file to a remote machine in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my code which is standard code to copy a file to any remote computer.

But it keeps popping up this error:

> The network path was not found.

Please help me out !

```
IntPtr admin_token = default(IntPtr);
    WindowsIdentity wid_admin = null;
    WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null;
    IntPtr duplicate_token = default(IntPtr);
    if (LogonUser("Administrator", "WIN-ABC", "aaaaaaa", 9, 0, ref admin_token) != 0)
        {
        if (DuplicateToken(admin_token, 2, ref duplicate_token) != 0)
            {
            wid_admin = new WindowsIdentity(duplicate_token);
            wic = wid_admin.Impersonate();
            System.IO.File.Copy("E:/abc.txt", "\\\\WIN-ABC\\Data1\\abc.txt", true);
        }
```

Comment: are you able to access this *\\\\WIN-ABC\\TestFolder\\abc.txt* path from your web server??

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: Login to your web server where this asp site is hosted......or are you runnning this is your local machine??

Comment: currently running on localhost of my local machine..

Comment: so locally are you able top access that networkpath??

Comment: n how to check that VIRU?

Comment: see, this function LogonUser() is returning me a token ! That means i am able to get into that machine..the error says that the path is wrong. Now when i provide this path to RUN in the destination machine,it is able to reach the file.

Comment: Go to Run and enter \\WIN-ABC\TestFolder\abc.txt path

Comment: I am assuming here Win-ABC is correct server name and TestFolder is shared folder

Comment: definitely, they all exist ! It seems to be some permission issues on that folder. i even gave all the rights to that folder but the issue still persists !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102957/discussion-between-user1172910-and-viru).

Comment: Sorry I cant do chat...my workplace firewall does not allow that....I get your problem....you are impersonating user but that credential is not delegated when you try to access remote path....that is why you get the error....

Comment: Try the code I just posted

Answer (score -1):

Try this code...this should allow you to access remote path

```
IntPtr admin_token = default(IntPtr);
            IntPtr duplicate_token = default(IntPtr);
            WindowsIdentity wid_admin = null;
            WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null;

           if (LogonUser("Administrator", "WIN-ABC", "ABCDEF", 9, 0, ref admin_token) != 0)
            {
                if (DuplicateToken(admin_token, 2, ref duplicate_token) != 0)
                {
                    wid_admin = new WindowsIdentity(duplicate_token);
                    wic = wid_admin.Impersonate();

                   System.IO.File.Copy("E:/Temp/abc.txt", "\\\\WIN-ABC\\TestFolder\\abc.txt", true)
                }
            }
```

Make sure you are adding below Import statement

```
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, 
       int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken);
```

Comment: naah...same issue...m i missing something here?

Comment: Also remove domain name WIN-ABC from first parameter..updated in answer too

Comment: IntPtr admin_token = default(IntPtr);
        WindowsIdentity wid_admin = null;
        WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null;
        IntPtr duplicate_token = default(IntPtr);
        if (LogonUser("Administrator", "WIN-ABC", "aaaa", 9, 0, ref admin_token) != 0)
            {
            if (DuplicateToken(admin_token, 2, ref duplicate_token) != 0)
                {
                wid_admin = new WindowsIdentity(duplicate_token);
                wic = wid_admin.Impersonate();
                System.IO.File.Copy("E:/Temp/abc.txt", "\\\\WIN-ABC\\Data\\abc.txt", true);
            }

Comment: What is local OS? on what is OS on remote machine?

Comment: Local Machine's OS - Win 10, Destination/Remote Machine's OS- Win Server 2008 enterprise SP2.

Comment: @ Downvoter pls explain reason to downvote....That will give me chance to improve my answer